# INTERSECT two table of size 500ml rows in vertica

Tags: sql, etl, database-performance, query-performance, vertica

I am very new to vertica db and hence looking for different efficient ways for comparing two tables of average size 500ml-800ml rows in vertica. I have a process that gets the data from vertica view and dump in to SQL server for later merge to final table in sql server. for few large tables combine it is dumping about 3bl rows daily. Instead of dumping all data I want to take daily snapshot, and compare it with previous days snapshot on vertica side only and then push changed rows only in to SQL SEREVER.

lets say previous snapshot is stored in tableA, today's snapshot stored in tableB. PK on both table is column named OrderId.

Simplest way I can think of is

```
Select * from tableB
Where OrderId NOT IN (

SELECT * from tableA
INTERSECT
SELECT * from tbleB
)
```

So my questions are:

1. Is there any other/better option in vertica to get only changed rows between two tables? Or should I 
   even consider doing this compare on vertica side?
2. How much doing such comparison should take?
3. What should I consider to improve the performance of such query?

Comment: I don't think your code will run on Vertica, unless the tables have only one column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your columns have no `NULL` values, then a massive `LEFT JOIN` would seem to do what you want:

```
select b.*
from tableB b left join
     tableA a
     on b.OrderId = a.OrderId and
        b.col1 = a.col1 and
        . . .   -- for all the columns you care about
```

However, I think you want [`except`](https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Statements/SELECT/EXCEPTClause.htm):

```
select b.*
from tableB b
except
select a.*
from tableA a;
```

I imagine this would have reasonable performance.

Comment: thanks. yes I guess EXCEPT is also option as I do not have use case of "rows exists in tableA but not in tableB"

Comment: because I care about all the columns LEFT JOIN is not a good option for me. except/intersect seems much cleaner way.

Comment: about the "reasonable performance" have you actually worked with vertica at large volume table? I was looking for rough estimate like this should take under 30sec or 1min etc.... I would like to know if any vertica cluster level configuration things I need to discuss with vertica dba if the performance is not under few seconds.
So i was hoping if you have any pointer for me to look in to.

Comment: @anupShah . . . You should talk to YOUR dba if this is specifically about your configuration.

Comment: Hi just to let you know there might be more options and ways but today I tried comparing two tables, 250ml row in each,  with 20ml rows having difference and it finished in 2min using EXCEPT approach. So that was acceptable for my workflow at the moment so I mark accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a primary key in the two tables?

Then my technique, for a complete Change Data Capture, is:

```
SELECT
 'I' AS to_do
, newrows.*
FROM tb_today     newrows
LEFT
JOIN tb_yesterday oldrows USING(id)
WHERE oldrows.id IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT
  'U' AS to_do
, newrows.*
FROM tb_today     newrows
JOIN tb_yesterday oldrows
WHERE oldrows.fname   <> newrows.fname
   OR oldrows.lnamd   <> newrows.lname
   OR oldrows.bdate   <> newrwos.bdate
   OR oldrows.sal     <> newrows.sal
 [...]
   OR oldrows.lastcol <> newrows.lastcol
UNION ALL
SELECT
 'D' AS to_do
, oldrows.*
FROM tb_yesterday oldrows
LEFT
JOIN tb_today     oldrows USING(id)
WHERE newrows.id IS NULL
;
```

Just leave out the last leg of the UNION SELECT if you don't want to cater for DELETEs ('D')

Good luck

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the response. But as I have 70+ columns, unless this technique has some major advantage on performance or something else, isn't the INTERSECT/EXCEPT is cleaner to read and write as I don't have to write all the column comparisons?

Comment: The EXCEPT operator is as easy to code as the UNION operator, yes. But a join over a primary key (which causes both tables, by default, to be both ordered and segmented by the primary key, thus having the optimal access path for that) is by orders of magnitude less resource intensive than a hash over all 70+ columns of the table, as it becomes necessary for a UNION (implying DISTINCT) or an EXCEPT/INTERSECT. The 70+ comparisons happen within a row that is being treated, and much less expensive. Plus, you can generate the statement from the `columns` system table.

Answer (score -1):

you also do it nicely using joins:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM tableB AS b 
LEFT JOIN tableA AS a ON a.id = b.id
WHERE a.id IS NULL
```

so above query return only diff from TableB to TableA i.e. data which is present in both table will be skipped...

Comment: Intersect is comparing all the columns. Not only PK column. When you do the LFET JOIN it is only check if that PK value exeist it not. IF EXIST it does not check all columns if the value for them are same or not. So it is not the same logic as INTERSECT.